# Class Library Access in WCF

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have two classes in two files in a class library project, they are:

```
Public Class Logins
    Public CurrentUser As Login
    Public Function Authenticate(ByVal id As String, ByVal pw As String)
        Dim adpt As New WorkMateDataSetTableAdapters.LoginsTableAdapter
        For Each k As WorkMateDataSet.LoginsRow In adpt.GetDataByUserName(id)
            If String.Equals(k.UserPW, pw) Then
                CurrentUser = New Login(k.UserName, k.UserPW, k.UserType)
                Return CurrentUser
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
        CurrentUser = Nothing
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Login
    Private _UserName As String
    Private _UserPW As String
    Private _UserType As String

    Property UserName
        Get
            Return _UserName
        End Get
        Set(value)
            _UserName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property UserPW
        Get
            Return _UserPW
        End Get
        Set(value)
            _UserPW = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Property UserType
        Get
            Return _UserType
        End Get
        Set(value)
            _UserType = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New()
        UserName = ""
        UserPW = ""
        UserType = ""
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal Namee As String, ByVal pw As String, ByVal typee As String)
        UserName = Namee
        UserPW = pw
        UserType = typee
    End Sub

End Class
```

the other class is:

```
public Class Courses
    Public CoursesOffered As List(Of Course)
End Class

Public Class Course
    'Cource name, Exams, Papers
    Private _CourseCategory As String
    Private _CourseID As String
    Public _Sems As New List(Of Sem)
End Class
```

I used a WCF service using net.tcp connection, however, the issue is that I am able to use the login original classes directly like (    Public Logins As New ServiceLogins.Logins), but I am not able to the course class like that.

Following is the code for the two WCF services:

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface IService1

    <OperationContract()>
    Function Test(ByVal value As Integer) As WorkMateLib.Course

    <OperationContract()>
    Function GetData(ByVal value As Integer) As String

    ' TODO: Add your service operations here

End Interface

and the other file is:


Imports System.ServiceModel

' NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the context menu to change the interface name "ILoginsRelated" in both code and config file together.
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface ILoginsRelated

    <OperationContract()>
    Function Authentication(ByVal login As WorkMateLib.Login) As WorkMateLib.Login

End Interface
```

Your help in this issue is appreciated.  Thank you.

Edit:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WorkMateWCF.WorkMateWCFService1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WorkMateWCF.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8523/WorkMateWCFServiceHost" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="WorkMateWCF.LoginsRelated">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WorkMateWCF.ILoginsRelated">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8732/WCFLoginsHost" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve but the *Course* class only exposes one public property named **_sem** that WCF will serialize as an array of Sem type objects. You should have no problems using the Courses type in the service code but since it is **not** part of the service contract, it is not available to clients consuming that service contract.

EDIT:

To make Courses available to the clients, you could do something along the lines of this:

```
 '''''''Rest of contract snipped

 <OperationContract()>
 Function GetCourses() As WorkMateLib.Courses

 '''''''Rest of contract snipped
```

The key is to add any class in the service you want exposed to clients part of the service contract by referencing it as either an input parameter or an output value of a service operation (function).

Comment: Could you please advice me on how I could make it a part of service contract.  Thank you.

Comment: @Sixto Saez, I tried it, but this way I am supposed to initiate a service client and then get it, but in my logins service, I did not initiate the login service to get the class.

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure how the client would have access to the Logins class based on the service contract shown. Could you add the portion of the WSDL XML that shows the Logins defined as part of the ILoginsRelated service contract to you question text? That may offer a clue of how the reference to Logins was made.

Comment: The answer at this [question shows how to configure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130366/wcf-nettcpbinding-with-mex) the netTcpBinding to display the metadata endpoint (mex). The metadata is the WSDL document I was referring to.

Comment: The setting `serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"` setting in the behavior element will prevent the WSDL from being displayed by your service. The easiest thing to do to get the WSDL is to [create a basicHttpBinding endpoint for displaying it in a browser.](http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2006/10/16/Metadata-Exchange-Endpoint.aspx)

Comment: I dont want the WCF to user internet, it is a lan app, so I used the TCP.

Comment: This would be only be for troubleshooting to see the Wsdl XML.